# how to hide login screen if the user already signed in

Tags: codenameone

```
In my app the first/main screen is login form. How to skip the login form
if he/she has already signed in? Presently every time, someone use the app,
the login form opens first.
```

How can I achieve this functionality in codename one. I didn't find anything in the group. Is there some tutorial or eg on doing this? Moreover I want the login form if someone logged out and then use the app. Thankyou

// change initial form:

```
@Override
protected String getFirstFormName() {
    loginToken = Preferences.get("loginToken", null);
    if (loginToken != null) {
        return "MenuForm";
    } else {
        return "Login";
    }
}
```

Comment: Save a bool value in NSUSerDefaults and compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if this is the first activation ever use preferences:

```
String loginToken = Preferences.get("loginToken", null);
if(loginToken == null) {
    // show login and after you get a token do
    Preferences.set("loginToken", loginToken);
}
```

This assumes you have a token representing the used identity but you can use the username, email or whatever you need for login.

Comment: hello.. I use gui builder code with statemachines. After I get the loginToken, how can I change the initial form or main form so that after user had already logged in, the login form is not displayed. I override getFirstFormName (code abov in question updated). Is it the right way to do so?

Comment: I think it is. Not really sure.